# C++ initializer list constraint checking

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I'm trying to explicitly cap the maximum size for a class I'm creating and have come up with a solution that appears to work but seems ugly. The example is somewhat contrived, but I'd like to know in case the situation ever arises more naturally.

Here it is as is:

```
PriorityQueue(const unsigned int maxSizeIn) :
            maxSize((maxSizeIn >= SOME_CONSTANT) ? SOME_CONSTANT - 1 : maxSizeIn),
            queueArray(new PriorityPair<T>*[maxSizeIn]()),
            currentHeapSize(0)
{

}
```

The clunkiness comes from having the ternary expression in the intializer list. While this does work, it doesn't look particularly good an forced me to separate by line each component of the list. I attempted to move that logic into the body of the constructor but I ran into issues with how I tried that.

For clarity's sake, I've edited the original to better highlight what I'm asking. That is, is there a functionally equivalent way that is more clean to put constraints on initializer lists.

What should be the go-to solution for a problem like this?

Comment: Why can't `maxSizeIn` equal`numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`?

Comment: @NathanOliver that part is arbitrary. I'm more concerned with the clunkiness of the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

You would use [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) for that:

```
maxSize(std::min(maxSizeIn, std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() - 1));
```

Here, `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() - 1` can be any constant whatsoever - in your example that would be `SOME_CONSTANT`.

Although note that it doesn't make sense whatsoever in your case. `maxSizeIn` can never be greater than the maximum value of its type. If someone were to specify a greater size than `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` to your constructor, that person will quickly notice that their argument has overflowed.

You could pass a `unsigned long` instead though.

Comment: I've edited the original post to better highlight what it is I'm asking. The example I went with was poorly contrived. I suppose std::min would make the solution ever so slightly shorter and cleaner, even if it is just a rapper on it. The brackets you have after maxSize, is that valid syntax for an intializer list?

Comment: @Caboose Yes, that's a C++11 feature. I'll change it though :)

Comment: @Caboose Your clarification doesn't really clarify for me. You can still use `std::min` for any `SOME_CONSTANT` that you have. You mean like more complicated constraints?

Comment: I changed it to highlight that I don't care about the what the maximum value is, and that the fact that a literal overflow of an unsigned int is not what I'm concerned with. Instead the question is about the best way to put _some_ arbitrary constraints on a value in an initializer list, or whether I'd be forced to do that in the constructor for clean reading.